# Getting error "libbrotli needed" when compiling woff2

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, brotli, woff2

I am trying to compile **google/woff2** for 3 days but getting error **"libbrotli needed"**. I was able compile brotli by running **CMakeLists.txt** in brotli folder and got .so files. I am beginner so I don't know to link both together. I want to compile and add brotli from **CMakeLists.txt** in woff2 folder or at least somehow compile linux build for woff2.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you need to compile and **install** *brotli* on your machine before you can compile *google/woff2*. The installation process is actually copying the .so and header file to somewhere on your system path that CMake is able to find it.

For example, you can you use this command to install the library to "/home/myuser/installdir"

```
cmake --install . --prefix "/home/myuser/installdir"
```

Comment: Can I put them on same director, Cmake will be able to find them there.

Comment: Brotli is a separate library (also included in 'woff2') https://github.com/google/brotli/tree/533843e3546cd24c8344eaa899c6b0b681c8d222 ...... see README.md : Default is `make install`

Comment: @KnudLarsen, I know brotli is a separate library. I want to build it together with woff2 or it will cause architecture related errors.

Comment: @KimNinh, If I place pre-build brotli library somewhere it will cause architecture related issues.

Comment: I tried to put them in the same folder but still got the error.

Comment: @PorushManjhi You want to build the library just for Android OS, isn't it? Well, if that is true, I'm afraid the build process is a little more complicated. The command above is just applied for "producer" and "consumer" of the library at the same OS. If you want to build the library and then use it on Android, try asking for build instructions on GitHub of that repository.

Answer (score 0):

Build **woff2** with libbrotli included in the executable

> woff2/README.md says:
>
> git clone --recursive https://github.com/google/woff2.git && cd woff2/ && make clean all

I.e. the woff2 executable´s can be built and used in the woff2/ directory, or can be copied to any location.

```
cd new-Folder/ 
git clone --recursive
https://github.com/google/woff2.git 
cd woff2/ 
make clean all    ## brotli libs and woff2 are built ... together

## executable: {woff2_compress, woff2_decompress, woff2_info}

       ## compress example
./woff2_compress satluj.ttf 
Processing satluj.ttf => satluj.woff2
Compressed 45526 to 21423.
```

P.S.: Many of the "Linux OS" have `woff2` (and libbrotli) available as a package, name = `woff2` or `woff2-tools`.

Comment: I already tried this method but it doesn't compile shared libraries for android architecture. That's why I want to generate them using android studio (using android toolchain).

Comment: Why shared libs ? ...... You don't get shared with `cd woff2/ &&  make clean all`

Comment: You mean .so files, I am getting them using "make clean all".